# access query is not returning all relevent records

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to create a query that will return all of the customer ID's from multiple tables as well as the monetary amounts that go with each of the customer codes. However, instead of pulling in every customer code from each of the tables in the query, it only pulls in a random selection of the codes. Any idea what could be causing this to happen? I apologize if I explained it poorly, if you have questions ask away. I've also attached a snapshot of the query design view below.

[query design image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MHQUs.png)

Comment: We have no idea what is causing this, because we can't even see the query you are running.  Please edit your question and include all relevant information.  Table structure and the query would probably be enough.

Comment: You need to provide your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `INNER JOINS` in your query, which means only rows that exist *in all joined tables* are returned. So if you have a customer that purchased items in 2014 but not 2015, then their name will be excluded.

If I understand what you are attempting, you want to use `LEFT` or `RIGHT` Joins, which will return *all* rows from KNOXLIVE_SLCUSTM and only rows from the other tables when a match is found.

So if you do not know SQL, right-click each join line in the query designer, and select join properties.

Depending on which order the tables were initially added either the second or third radio button will be the join you want. Choose the one that selects ALL records from KNOXLIVE_SLCUSTM. Do that for all four joins and re-run your query.

Comment: That worked pretty well! It technically did what I need it to.. However, I only need the records that appear in all of the other tables that ALSO appear in SLCUSTM. The problem with returning all records from SLCUSTM is that there are thousands of records (customers). With that being said, I tried switching the join property to the selection that says it would pull all from each of the and only the ones from SLCUSTM that match, but it doesn't work.

Comment: @lucky123 I'm not totally following, try adding criteria to your sales column to omit the records you don't want. `WHERE [2015 Sales].SumOfVal > 0` or just put ">0" in the criteria row of whichever column you want to test.